# Design Bowl but... UI-WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair

Tags: openscad

I am attempting to create a design on OpenSCAD. Is there a mathematical formula to get the right result?

Here is the code I have created:

```
$fn=60;
module Bowl(diameter,thickness)
{
    rim=thickness/2;
    half=diameter/2;
    union(){
        // Main Bowl
        difference(){
            // Outer Ball
            sphere(d=diameter);
            // Inner Ball
            sphere(d=diameter-thickness*2);
            // Cutting Cube
            translate([-half-0.5,-half-0.5,-half])
            cube([diameter+1,diameter+1,half+rim]);
        }
        // Rim
        translate([0,0,rim])
        difference(){
            // Torus
            rotate_extrude()
            translate([(diameter-thickness)/2,0,0])
            circle(d=thickness);
            // Cutting Cube
            translate([-half-0.5,-half-0.5,0])
            cube([diameter+1,diameter+1,rim+1]);
        }
    }
}
rotate([0,180,0])
Bowl(7,1);
```

The shape here is a bowl with a rounded rim and semicircular from the side
The ideal shape should be smooth with no edges, however, the current one has because the rim and the main body cannot align.

It gives the error message:

> UI-WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the cutting cube for the torus, seems the face touching is confusing it.
I think this is what you want without doing the geometry:

```
$fn=200;
module Bowl(diameter,thickness)
{
    rim=thickness/2;
    half=diameter/2;

    // Main Bowl
    #difference(){
        // Outer Ball
        sphere(d=diameter);
        // Inner Ball
        sphere(d=diameter-thickness*2);
        // Cutting Cube
        translate([-half-0.5,-half-0.5,-half])
        cube([diameter+1,diameter+1,half]);
    }
    // Rim
    difference(){
        // Torus
        rotate_extrude()
        translate([(diameter-thickness)/2,0,0])
        circle(d=thickness);
    }
}
rotate([0,180,0])
Bowl(7,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the complete profile in 2D before the rotate_extrude

```
$fn=60;
module Bowl(diameter,thickness)
{
    rim=thickness/2;
    half=diameter/2;    
     rotate_extrude() 
     offset( rim/2)    
     offset(-rim ) 
     offset( rim/2)
    union(){
        // Main Bowl
      intersection(){
          difference(){
            // Outer "Ball"
            circle(d=diameter);
            // Inner "Ball"
            circle(d=diameter-thickness*2);
          }
          // Cutting "Cube"
          translate([0,rim]) mirror([0,1])
            square([diameter+1,diameter+1 ]);
        }
        // Rim
            translate([(diameter-thickness)/2,rim ])
            circle(d=thickness); 
        }
    }
```